# iFrame Uses Background Image From Host Body

Tags: html, css, iframe, background-color

I have a page with a few iframes on it which refresh on their own showing certain data. Problem is the background image is setting itself on the iframe backgrounds as well. The iframe pages link to the same CSS file as the main page but I have that page using different IDs and classes but the background image is still showing in the iframes. On the host page I have a CSS file stating the image file for the background.

```
body {
background-image: url (background1.jpg);
}
```

The iFrames look like so:

```
<iframe src="File.php" width="100px" height="100px" frameborder="0"></frame>
```

I have tried the `allowtransparency` attribute but that does nothing. I have tried specifying a background color in the CSS for the iFrame page for itself and it does nothing. Is it not possible to change the background of the iFrame page while the body tag is setting a URL image?

Answer (score 0):

add attr in iframe

```
style="background-color:SET YOUR COLOR"
```

Comment: I have tried that. It still uses the background-image.

Answer (score 0):

use position relative with iframe

```
position:relative; z-index:99;
```